# Conditional without the if clause?

Tags: python, function, conditional-statements

```
def count_emma(statement):
    print("Given String: ", statement)
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(statement) - 1):
        count += statement[i: i + 4] == 'Emma'
    return count

count = count_emma("Emma is good developer. Emma is a writer")
print("Emma appeared ", count, "times")
```

In this program I have to find out the number of times "Emma" appears in the statement: "Emma is good developer. Emma is a writer".

MY QUESTION: I can't understand what is going on in line 5. How is it a conditional without the if clause? And how does the count increment by 1 each time "Emma" appears in the statement?

Comment: "Emma is good developer. Emma is a writer".count("Emma")

Comment: `True` equals `1`, `False` equals `0`, so you just add `1` if condition is true and add `0` if it's false.

Comment: `count += statement[i: i + 4] == 'Emma'` statement is doing the job but I don't think it's pythonic.

Comment: @VishalSingh yeah i can't really get how it is doing the job

Comment: It is not a good example to follow. `if .... : count += 1` would be a lot clearer and more maintainable (although there are also other ways of tackling the overall problem).

Comment: ... but how it works is that the `==` operator gives a boolean (`True` or `False`) but that when you add an integer and a boolean, the boolean is converted to integer (1 or 0 respectively) for the calculation.

Comment: Yeah that is indeed a lot clear way @alaniwi. But i still wanted to know how this thing works. Thanks , i get it now :)

Answer (score 3):

For a start, there is *no* requirement that a conditional be used exclusively with `if`. Even putting aside the possibility that you can use if with `while`, you can bind a conditional to a variable or otherwise use it in other ways:

```
>>> x = (1 < 2) ; print(x)
True
>>> print(10 < 4)
False
```

A conditional, in the context where an *integer* is needed, will be `1` for true and `0` for false, as per the following transcript:

```
>>> count = 0
>>> count += (7 > 2) ; print(count)
1
>>> count += (7 > 20) ; print(count)
1
```

Hence, for every starting position in the string, we add one if `Emma` is found there, or zero otherwise.

Unfortunately, that's also going to pick up any mentions of her brother, Emmanuel, so you may want to take that into account. *One* way to do that would be to ensure there are are spaces at the front and back, and replace all non-alpha characters with spaces, then just use `string.count()` to count how many time `Emma` appears with spaces on either side:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = "Emma is good developer. Emma is a writer. Emmanuel is her brother."
>>> re.sub("[^A-Za-z]+", " ", f" {x} ").count(" Emma ")
2
```

There are possibly many *other* ways as well, I'm just more used to regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clear and precise explanation. (:

Answer (score 0):

In python there is an automatic casting. So when you add an integer and a float, the integer is converted to floats and then the operation is performed.

For example, `print(2 + 2)` would just show `4` but `print(2+2.0)` will show you 4.0 that is because the integer `2` is casted to a float.

The same thing happens when you add an integer and a boolean the boolean is casted to an integer.

This for example, `print(True + 2)` shows 3

But this doesn't only work with addition operation, but also comparasion.

For instance, doing  both `print(2==2.0)` and `print(True == 1)` should print `True` as `2` is converted to floats first and also as `True` is converted to an integer.

So in your program the same thing happens.
First `statement[i: i + 4] == 'Emma'` returns `True` or `False` depending on the values. Then `count += statement[i: i + 4] == 'Emma'`, which is equvalent with `count = count + statement[i: i + 4] == 'Emma'`, will perform a boolean and  an integer addition. As I told you above this will result in the boolean being casted to an integers and the operation is performed.

Comment: Wow, I totally get it now. Thanks a lot ^_^